# Loop over vector containing NULL

Tags: r

I want to loop over a vector and send the values as parameters to a function. One of the values I want to send is NULL. This is what I've been trying

```
things <- c('M','F',NULL)
for (thing in things){
    doSomething(thing)
}
```

But the loop ignores the NULL value. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The loop doesn't ignore it. Look at `things` and you'll see that the `NULL` isn't there.

You can't mix types in a vector, so you can't have both `"character"` and `"NULL"` types in the same vector.  Use a list instead.

```
things <- list('M','F',NULL)
for (thing in things) {
  print(thing)
}
[1] "M"
[1] "F"
NULL
```

Comment: You're right, I didn't check the vector to see if the NULL was actually there. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

When you construct a vector with `c()`, a value of NULL is ignored:

```
things <- c('M','F',NULL)
things
[1] "M" "F"
```

However, if it important to pass the `NULL` downstream, you can use a `list` instead:

```
things <- list('M','F',NULL)
for (thing in things){
  print(thing)
}
[1] "M"
[1] "F"
NULL
```